# When reading data from database it shows decimal value?

Tags: java, mysql, database, string

I am trying to read data from data from database it shows as decimal value.

The projectno field in database is varchar and the value is 10637.

But when i retrieve it shows the output as `10637.0 project no`

```
myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

String sql = "Select * FROM jtc_list  where jtcno='"+jtcnum+"' and materialclass='"+matclass+"'";

// create sql statement
myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

// execute query
myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

while(myRs.next()){
   projectno = myRs.getString("projectno");
   System.out.println(myRs.getString("projectno")+" project no");
}
```

How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `myRs`? Please show the code from the database query till when you print it.

Comment: @Marc I had edited my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should probably *not* be storing numeric data in a character column in your MySQL table.  That aside, you said:

> and the value is 10637

If the text value literally be `10637`, then you should absolutely see the following print statement:

```
10637 project no
```

If instead you saw:

```
10637.0 project no
```

then it means you stored `10637.0` in the column as text.

The general best thing to do here is:

- Store numeric data in a numeric column (e.g. `INT`, `DECIMAL`, `NUMERIC`).
- When retrieving numeric data, e.g. integer data, from your table, use `ResultSet#getInt()`.
- If you want to *view* your numeric data a certain way, then either handle the formatting from your MySQL query, or do so from your Java code.

Comment: Thanks bro I change the data type to Int in database.